# JavaScript - Clicking specific anchored tags, randomly

Tags: javascript, click

I've searched Google for awhile now, doesn't seem like I am correctly searching it though. Sorry if this is already out there. =/

Alright, say there are fifty anchored tags on one page. All the anchored tags you want to click have the same class attribute, but you don't want to click the same one twice in a row.

How would I do this? Keep in mind their href attribute is different, so I assume that's one way we could count that it's already been clicked, or perhaps the innerHTML of the anchored tag?

[{ Can't post images - https://i.stack.imgur.com/orTyE.png }]

Like say I wanted to click all the anchored tags except these, "Links, Images, Styling/Headers, Lists, Blockquotes, Code, HTML". But, I don't want to click the same one twice.

Comment: What do you mean by 'click all the anchored tags except these, "Links, Images, Styling/Headers, Lists, Blockquotes, Code, HTML"'?

Comment: I was referring to the image, it was supposed to be an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop double clicking, you can use this(requires jQuery).

```
$("a.classAttr").click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
       $(this).addClass("clicked");
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, and jQuery is no problem. It'll help me either way.